# I have a function of List<string> that get string,int how can i use it to work?

Tags: c#

Edited:
Im trying to make recursive:
In the top of Form1 i have:

```
List<string> webSites = new List<string>();
        List<string> csFiles = new List<string>();
```

In the constructor i have:

```
webCrawler(url, 2);
```

Then i have the function getLinks:

```
private void getLinks()
        {
            foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
            {
                var href = link.Attributes["href"].Value;
                richTextBox1.Text += href + Environment.NewLine;
                webSites.Add(href);
            }
        }

private List<string> test(string url, int levels)
            {
                doc = hw.Load(url);
                getLinks();
                if (levels == 0)
                {
                    return csFiles;
                }
                else
                {
                    for (i = 0; i < webSites.Count(); i++)
                    {

                        string t = webSites[i];
                        var f = levels * test(url, levels - 1);

                    }
                }
                return csFiles;
            }
```

webSites and csFiles are both List and levels is int. 
The problem is that on the line: `var f = levels * test(url, levels - 1);`
On the right side im getting error: Error Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'System.Collections.Generic.List

How can i fix it ?

---

In the function test i also call the function getLinks()
I also need to make a function for the cs files that will take out from each site only .cs files and in the end in the test function i need to return the csFiles list.

Comment: You are trying to multiply a `List<string>` with an integer - what do you expect to happen?

Comment: this is recursive call, are you sure you want this ? Btw. you cannot use operator * between int and List

Comment: What are you trying to do? You are trying to multiply an integer by a list, which makes no sense. What operation do you think should be happening when you do `levels * test()` ?

Comment: Please specify what do you want to achive ?

Comment: Thank you for editing and explaining what you are trying to do with the function. But you need to explain why you are trying to do with `var f = levels * test(url, levels - 1);` - what is that supposed to mean? What is `f` and how are you trying to calculate it?

Comment: the var f is worng. Im not sure how to do it . But what i want to calculate or to do is recursive of the getLinks() function so in the end the list webSites will be with all the links from the first url and two levels inside. Then i need to use this recurisve also to get all the .cs files and add the .cs files to the list csFiles and return the list csFiles.  But i didnt make yet the function to calculate how ot get the csFiles. For now i know how to get only the links from the first wbsite. In general im trying to make recursive to get all links in two levels and get all .cs files

Comment: And its not have to be that the .cs files will be on my hard disk but at least to be in the list csFiles same as the webSites list.

Comment: is this homework for a class?

Answer (score 0):

In the Line: "var f = levels * test(url, levels - 1); "

f is set equal to the result of "levels" an int, and the result of the method "test(url, levels -1)".

the result of the method "test(url, levels - 1)" is a List of type string.

this means that you are attempting to multiply an integer and a List.

You can simply use .Count or .Length...

the line should read: "var f = levels * test(url, levels - 1).Count(); "

Answer (score 0):

feels like homework for a 100 level cs course, but assuming for the moment that it's not, I'll present this as an approach:

```
public static List<string> CrawlWithDepth(string url, int depth)
{
    var ret = new List<string>();
    var linksFromPage = GetLinks(url);
    ret.AddRange(linksFromPage);
    if (depth > 0)
    {
        foreach (var childLink in linksFromPage)
        {
            var childCrawlResults = CrawlWithDepth(childLink, depth - 1);
            ret.AddRange(childCrawlResults);
        }
    }
}

private static List<string> GetLinks(string url)
{
    var ret = new List<string>();
    foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
    {
        var href = link.Attributes["href"].Value;
        ret.Add(href);
    }
    return ret;
}
```